# Values of sum aggregate changing after joining queries

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I individually run three seperate queries for the SUM values I am getting the correct amounts but when I join the queries as shows below my values change. How do I aggregate only DISTINCT VALUES? I need this group by CUST_ID.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CUS.CUST_ID,
    VWC.DISPLAY_NM,
    VWC.PREFIX_NM,
    VWC.FIRST_NM,
    VWC.MIDDLE_NM,
    VWC.LAST_NM,
    VWC.SUFFIX_NM,
    VWC.STREET1,
    VWC.STREET2,
    VWC.CITY_NM,
    VWC.STATE_CD,
    VWC.POSTAL_CD,
    VWC.COUNTRY_CD,
    VWC.EMAIL,
    SUM(ACC.PAYMENT_FAMT) AS TOTALWRITEOFF,
    SUM(CUS.PAID) AS TOTALPAID,
    SUM(REC.BALANCE) AS TOTALBALANCE

    FROM
    AHR_VW_CUSTOMER VWC
    JOIN
    AR_VW_PAY_ACCT ACC 
    ON ACC.CUST_ID = VWC.CUST_ID
    JOIN
    AR_VW_CUS_ACCT CUS
    ON CUS.CUST_ID = ACC.CUST_ID
    JOIN
    AR_VW_CUS_ACCT_RECEIPT REC
    ON REC.CUST_ID=CUS.CUST_ID

    WHERE 
    ---CUS.CUST_ID = '00123044'
    ---AND
    (ACC.PAYMENT_TY='FDN - Writeoff Individul')

    GROUP BY
    CUS.CUST_ID,
    VWC.DISPLAY_NM,
    VWC.PREFIX_NM,
    VWC.FIRST_NM,
    VWC.MIDDLE_NM,
    VWC.LAST_NM,
    VWC.SUFFIX_NM,
    VWC.STREET1,
    VWC.STREET2,
    VWC.CITY_NM,
    VWC.STATE_CD,
    VWC.POSTAL_CD,
    VWC.COUNTRY_CD,
    VWC.EMAIL
    ORDER BY
    VWC.LAST_NM
```

Comment: You either need to sum before the join's or use an analytical function to sum() over (partition by all columns in join)

Comment: You can keep the three individual queries and just make them sub-queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use an analytical function; or generate the sums in subqueries before the joins.

I also have problems w/ your joins as you are negating your left joins by having where clause limits on tables on the right side of the left join.

```
CUS.CUST_ID = '00123044'
AND
(ACC.PAYMENT_TY='FDN - Writeoff Individul')
```

The above will eliminate the records from VWC that have no matching record; thus why a left join? use inner? or move these limits to the joins.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CUS.CUST_ID,
VWC.DISPLAY_NM,
VWC.PREFIX_NM,
VWC.FIRST_NM,
VWC.MIDDLE_NM,
VWC.LAST_NM,
VWC.SUFFIX_NM,
VWC.STREET1,
VWC.STREET2,
VWC.CITY_NM,
VWC.STATE_CD,
VWC.POSTAL_CD,
VWC.COUNTRY_CD,
VWC.EMAIL,
SUM(ACC.PAYMENT_FAMT) over (partition by ACC.CUST_ID) AS TOTALWRITEOFF,
SUM(CUS.PAID) over (partition by CUS.CUST_ID)AS TOTALPAID,
SUM(REC.BALANCE) over (partition by REC.CUST_ID)AS TOTALBALANCE

FROM AHR_VW_CUSTOMER VWC
JOIN AR_VW_PAY_ACCT ACC 
  ON ACC.CUST_ID = VWC.CUST_ID
 AND ACC.PAYMENT_TY='FDN - Writeoff Individul'
LEFT JOIN AR_VW_CUS_ACCT CUS
  ON CUS.CUST_ID = ACC.CUST_ID
 and CUS.CUST_ID = '00123044'
LEFT JOIN AR_VW_CUS_ACCT_RECEIPT REC
  ON REC.CUST_ID=CUS.CUST_ID

GROUP BY
CUS.CUST_ID,
VWC.DISPLAY_NM,
VWC.PREFIX_NM,
VWC.FIRST_NM,
VWC.MIDDLE_NM,
VWC.LAST_NM,
VWC.SUFFIX_NM,
VWC.STREET1,
VWC.STREET2,
VWC.CITY_NM,
VWC.STATE_CD,
VWC.POSTAL_CD,
VWC.COUNTRY_CD,
VWC.EMAIL
ORDER BY
VWC.LAST_NM
```

Or as calculate totals before the joins.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CUS.CUST_ID,
VWC.DISPLAY_NM,
VWC.PREFIX_NM,
VWC.FIRST_NM,
VWC.MIDDLE_NM,
VWC.LAST_NM,
VWC.SUFFIX_NM,
VWC.STREET1,
VWC.STREET2,
VWC.CITY_NM,
VWC.STATE_CD,
VWC.POSTAL_CD,
VWC.COUNTRY_CD,
VWC.EMAIL,
Sum_PAYMENT_FAMT AS TOTALWRITEOFF,
SUM_PAID AS TOTALPAID,
SUM_Balance  AS TOTALBALANCE

FROM AHR_VW_CUSTOMER VWC
JOIN (SELECT SUM(PAYMENT_FAMT) SUM_Payment_FAMT, CUST_ID 
      FROM AR_VW_PAY_ACCT
      GROUP BY CUST_ID) ACC 
  ON ACC.CUST_ID = VWC.CUST_ID
 AND  ACC.PAYMENT_TY='FDN - Writeoff Individul'
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(PAID) sum_Paid, CUST_ID 
           FROM AR_VW_CUS_ACCT
           GROUP BY CUST_ID) CUS
  ON CUS.CUST_ID = ACC.CUST_ID
 AND CUS.CUST_ID = '00123044'
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(BALANCE) Sum_Balance, CUST_ID
           FROM AR_VW_CUS_ACCT_RECEIPT 
           GROUP BY CUST_ID) REC
  ON REC.CUST_ID=CUS.CUST_ID
--  WHERE CUS.CUST_ID = '00123044'
--    AND  (ACC.PAYMENT_TY='FDN - Writeoff Individul')

GROUP BY
CUS.CUST_ID,
VWC.DISPLAY_NM,
VWC.PREFIX_NM,
VWC.FIRST_NM,
VWC.MIDDLE_NM,
VWC.LAST_NM,
VWC.SUFFIX_NM,
VWC.STREET1,
VWC.STREET2,
VWC.CITY_NM,
VWC.STATE_CD,
VWC.POSTAL_CD,
VWC.COUNTRY_CD,
VWC.EMAIL
ORDER BY
VWC.LAST_NM
```

Or you could calculate the totals in the select but I find the performance poor as the select has to be run once for each cust_ID

SELECT...

```
(SELECT SUM(PAYMENT_FAMT) 
 FROM AR_VW_PAY_ACCT ACC 
 WHERE ACC.CUST_ID = VWC.CUST_ID) AS TOTALWRITEOFF, --uses correlated query
```

Comment: I tried it that way and got the same incorrect values

Comment: It's because of the left join and where clause criteria I think.  you are negating your left joins (making them behave like inner joins).  move the limits to the joins.

Comment: I had them as inner joins I just re-wrote them as LEFT JOINS to see if it would change anything my apologies.

Comment: and the only limit I need working is WHERE = ACC.PAYMENT_TY='FDN - Writeoff Individul'.  I need the query to pull by all customer id's

Comment: Ok, when you say incorrect values, can you site a few examples and some sample data: setup the problem on http://rextester.com/ as I'm not able to see what  is incorrect.